# Reference last object that was called?

Tags: python

Im sure this was asked before, but when searching for it i only found questions like "reference last object in a list"

However, i am looking for something to make this example code not redundant - in this example i have to use two very long variables:

```
if response.json()["items"][0]["id"]:
   print(response.json()["items"][0]["id"])
```

I know that powershell has $_., and im wondering if Python has something similar, so that i do not have to reference the same variable twice (for example if it is not just a small x, but a longer name like an object out of a dictionary etc.)

Comment: I dont understand! Can u give an example of how this code would be redundant in Powershell?

Comment: How about `def print_if(x): if x: print(x)` and then write `print_if(long_name)` everywhere else?

Comment: That would be an error-prone obfuscation tool. I'm glad we don't have it.

Comment: Use the `:=` operator introduced in 3.8: `if (x := <some lookup expression here>): print(x)`

Comment: exactly what im looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the first example here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html

You can use the `walrus operator` (python 3.8) which does exactly what you want:

```
if (x := <long expression>):
    print(x)
```